# How to redirect to a dynamic url after sign in using nextauth.js?

Tags: authentication, next.js, callback, middleware, next-auth

I have been trying to make this work for a while and just can't seem to find any solution in the docs for the problem I have. The situation is this, I want a user to sign in using nextauth.js, and upon successful sign in, be redirected to their profile which lives on a url like this, /[role]/u/[username]. Both role and username are saved to the user object in a database so what I really need is access to the user during the sign in flow. The options in the docs say to use a callbackUrl which won't work because it looks like this:

```
'use client'

const {data:session} = useSession();

const onClick = () => {
 signIn('google',{
  callbackUrl: `/${session.user.role}/u/${session.user.username}`
 })
}
```

The reason this doesn't work is you can't access the session data before they're logged in, it returns undefined. Using the redirect callback gives you access to the url and baseUrl but not the user so again the same problem persists. Using the signIn callback allows access to the data but if you return a url instead of true it does redirect to the url but cancels the auth flow so the user doesn't actually get logged in.

Is there a way that I'm missing, either in a callback or by passing a url to the signIn function that will allow me to redirect to /[role]/u/[username] successfully after signing in?

I've tried everything mentioned in the nextauth docs as explained above. I'm also trying to avoid using a useEffect to redirect to avoid flashing content.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a clean way to implement this with current NextAuth API. However, you can achieve the desired behavior by disabling the default redirect and redirecting your users manually.

```js
'use client'

const router = useRouter();
const { data: session } = useSession();

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (session) {
    router.push(`/${session.user.role}/u/${session.user.username}`);
  }
}, [session, router])

const onClick = () => {
  signIn('google', { redirect: false });
}
```